# prevent userform textbox exit code from running on button click

Tags: excel, vba

I have recently started using a userform in order control the capture information in an excel spreadsheet that is then used by a subsequent macro. The form has a series of textboxes and then buttons to either do stuff or cancel the form.

The code for the Done and Cancel buttons is as follows:

```
Private Sub buttonAddAndDone_Click()
    DoStuff
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub buttonCancel_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

I was asked to put validation on the textboxes within the form so that as they are populated the information is checked using the below structure. In some cases it is to force an entry, others it checks whether it is a date or numeric but the structure of the code is like this:

```
Private Sub Control_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)

    If (IsNull(Control.Value)) Or Control.Value = "" Then
        MyAnswer = MsgBox("Control Value is necessary", vbExclamation, "Macro Error")
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This has caused a problem whereby if the user clicks the Cancel button, the Control_Exit code runs and throws up the MsgBox and the user cannot close the form without putting any input in.

Is it possible to prevent the control_exit code running following the press of the cancel button?

Comment: Why don't you just `Unload Me` instead of `Cancel = True`? But why cancel at all the form just because an entry in a TextBox fails the validation? Why not leave the form open and give the user another try to enter a correct value. But that I mean to just remove the line `Cancel = True`. Done.

Comment: The person who requested this wanted it so that if the validation failed the focus remained on the control in question. I researched this on Stack and found that including the cancel=true line achieved this result. So what I need to achieve is that this validation loop runs only if it is not the 'cancel' button being pressed.